# Date time to csv with Python

Tags: python, csv, date, time

I actually write a code, which one i am scraping a table from a website, and import to an CSV file. My question is, how can i make a new columns and put the actually date in every cells in this columns (while there are data).

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
header = ['Pénznem', 'Devizanév','Egység','Pénznem_Forintban', 'Dátum']
output.writerow(header)

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

soup=make_soup("https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok")

datatable=[]
for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        datatable.append(data.text)
maindatatable = to_2d(datatable, 4)

output.writerows(maindatatable)

resultcsv.close()

print maindatatable
```

Where i have to put and what i have to change in my date code, to get the correct result?

```
now = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
ido = to_2d(now, 5)
output.writerows(ido)
```

Comment: do you intend to "append" data to existing one ?

Comment: Probabably yes, because i have 4 columns which ones i am scraping from a website (its a table), and i want to make a 5. columns, where i can write the actually date in every rows.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of your code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(maindatatable)
now = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df['date'] = now
df.columns = header
df.to_csv(filename, sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: I get this error message:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\prohardver.py", line 49, in <module>
    df.to_csv('output2.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1403, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1586, in save
    self._save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1673,

Comment: in _save
    self._save_header()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1641, in _save_header
    writer.writerow(encoded_labels)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 527, in writerow
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte"

Comment: Hmm it works locally for me. Try changing encoding='utf-8' to encoding='ISO-8859-1'

Comment: It isnt work :(
Maybe you work with 3.x? I am using 2.7.13

Comment: I'm on 2.7.11. Please also try 'ISO 8859-16' or 'Windows-1250'

Comment: It is working with "latin-1", but i miss the header row!

Comment: What do you mean "you miss the header row"?

Comment: This row : "header = ['Pénznem', 'Devizanév','Egység','Pénznem_Forintban', 'Dátum']"  is disappear!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146766/discussion-between-stergios-and-tardos93).